# Zend Form dynamic row number with javascript

Tags: forms, zend-framework, zend-form

I have a form here in which there is a textfield which contains a number. In another part of the form there are rows, which coresponds with the number entered. For example 2 = 2 rows etc.
So my idea is to create one row which is duplicated by a javascript. So i must create a input element which name is in a array like name="input[]" how can i do this in Zend Framework?

The only approach i found for this kind of problem is to use subforms. But every Subform has a explicite name which is not in a array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a rendered `Zend_Form` respond to client-side changes - as in your example, to allow the user to enter the number of rows he wants - you need both client-side and server-handling.

The best example demonstrating the general idea is from Jeremy Kendall:

[jeremykendall.net » Blog Archive » Dynamically Adding Elements to Zend_Form](http://www.jeremykendall.net/2009/01/19/dynamically-adding-elements-to-zend-form/)

The upshot is that you have client-side code that adds tracks the number of fields and then a `preValidation()` method that injects the right number of fields into the `$form` instance before `isValid()` gets called.

[As noted in the comments there, this `preValidation()` processing could just be bundled into `isValid()` so that the controller remains unchanged.]